# MySQL query receives only 1 result

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which displays only 1 result. However, I have six rows in my database with product_id = '1'. I'm talking about `$order`, only one shows up, instead of six. What is wrong?

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM artikelbestelling WHERE product_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 500";
$doget = mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($doget))
{
$order = $row['ordernummer'];
$artikel = $row['artikelnummer'];
echo "<strong>$order</strong><br />";
}
```

My database structure:

id (primary & autoincrement)(int 11)

product_id (int 11)

number (int 11)

ordernummer (int 11)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Can you specify your table structure and/or data?

Comment: What does `echo mysql_num_rows($doget)` say after you've run the query? Can't see anything in your code snippet that'd abort the loop after a single itereation, so most likely you really are getting only a single result row.

Comment: Can't see any problems in your php, Can you run the query in an mysql-terminal?

Comment: See my updated question for my database structure!

Comment: Then check that $ordernummer is actually some value and not empty - view the source of the page you're generating,a nd you'll probably get a bunch of `<strong></strong><br />` chunks with nothing in them.

Comment: @MarcB it is some value and I'm not getting any <strong><strong><br /> chunks in my source code.. Strange!

Comment: in your list of database/table structure, you don't have a field named ordernummer

Comment: @PugganSe, sorry, forgot to type that!

Comment: tested your code, works fine at my server http://test.puggan.se/test/so_andre.php

Comment: So have you abandoned this question?  If you figured out what you were doing wrong, please post it as an answer to help those of us who want to help others with this issue know where to direct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your id is int, you dont need to use ''

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM artikelbestelling WHERE product_id = '1' LIMIT 0, 500";
$doget = mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($doget))
{
$order = $row['ordernummer'];
$artikel = $row['artikelnummer'];
echo "<strong>$order</strong><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that I notice immediately that *shouldn't* make a difference, but might be worth trying just to see if it does.  First, assuming that the product_id column is a numeric column instead of a string, try using just 1 instead of '1'.  Second, explicitly check the result of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` against FALSE instead of any expression that might evaluate equivalent to false.

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM artikelbestelling WHERE product_id = 1 LIMIT 0, 500";
$doget = mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($doget)) !== FALSE)
{
    $order = $row['ordernummer'];
    $artikel = $row['artikelnummer'];
    echo "<strong>$order</strong><br />";
}
```

**Edit:**

What do you get if you change your code to the following?

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM artikelbestelling WHERE product_id = 1 LIMIT 0, 500";
$doget = mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());

$index = 0;
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($doget)) !== FALSE)
{
    $order = $row['ordernummer'];
    $artikel = $row['artikelnummer'];
    echo $index++ . ": <strong>$order</strong><br />";
}
```

Specifically, does it count all the way from 0 to 7, or does it just show row 0?  I'm thinking that it's got to be one of the following:

- You really are only getting back one row of results (which is contradicted by your statement that `mysql_num_rows()` is returning 8),
- `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is incorrectly returning FALSE after just one row (which indicates some kind of bug affecting PHP or the MySQL driver, which is typically very unlikely), or
- it is iterating through the loop like it should be, but you are misinterpreting the result, per Marc B's comment regarding empty tags.

This might effectively help narrow down which it is.

Comment: I agree with his update, it looks as though he is referencing a string rather than a number

Comment: the `!==` part is pointless. if the fetch call returns false, the loop will abort anyways. in PHP, the result of an assignment is the value being assigned.

Comment: I'm well aware of that @Marc B.  My point is that sometimes things return values that evaluate to false that aren't explicitly FALSE.  For example, if the result of the mysql_fetch_assoc() call returns an empty array, 0, null, etc., it will end the while() loop even if there are more items that should be fetched.  In theory, mysql_fetch_assoc() *shouldn't* return such a value (which I noted in my answer), but when the documentation says that it returns FALSE, my best practice is to test explicitly against FALSE, not something that may be mistaken for false.

Comment: I can't see how fetch would do that. it either returns an array of data, or it returns false.it can't return an empty array - you can't select NOTHING, and if there's no data to be fetch (empty set), you'd just get false anyways.

Comment: Well to be blunt, if mysql_num_rows() returns 8 and he's only getting back one result in his loop, then something is already out of whack and maybe it's worthwhile to start checking things that you're assuming to make sure they're true.  It's called troubleshooting.  If the obvious stuff doesn't work (or there is no "obvious stuff"), then start checking the non-obvious.  This is about the second or third time I've had an answer downvoted while trying to help someone troubleshoot an issue and check assumptions.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM artikelbestelling WHERE product_id = '1'  
LIMIT 0, 500";
$doget = mysql_query($get) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($doget))
{
echo "$row[ordernummer]";
echo "<br />";
echo "$row[artikelnummer]";
}
```

Comment: and if possible, dont use '*' in your query unless you are gonna use all the fields. It is lazy, and not efficient. get in the habit of writing the field name instead...good luck